# EF Core 5 Sum difference between two date times

Tags: .net-5, ef-core-5.0

We have upgraded to net 5 / ef core 5, and many of our queries have needed "fixing" due to the changes that have been made.

In reality, the queries were horribly inefficient, because the LINQ could not be translated to SQL and now this has been brought to our attention; one solution is to force this to be worked on the client instead of the SQL Server... however I would like this to make this more efficient.

Below is a query that I can't find a way to do efficiently:

```
        DateTime toDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(NumberofDays + 1).Date;
        MyInsights.AvailableHours = DatabaseContext.WorkCenterSchedules
            .Where(x => x.ForWorkCenter.WorkCenterId == WorkCenterID && x.dateTo > DateTime.Now && x.dateTo < toDate)
            .Sum(y => (y.dateTo - (DateTime.Now > y.dateFrom ? DateTime.Now : y.dateFrom)).TotalMinutes) / 60;
```

The error is:

[image: error image]

This could be changed to the following:

```
        DateTime toDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(NumberofDays + 1).Date;
        List<WorkCenterSchedule> schedules = DatabaseContext.WorkCenterSchedules
            .Where(x => x.ForWorkCenter.WorkCenterId == WorkCenterID && x.dateTo > DateTime.Now && x.dateTo < toDate).ToList();
        MyInsights.AvailableHours = schedules.Sum(y => (y.dateTo - (DateTime.Now > y.dateFrom ? DateTime.Now : y.dateFrom)).TotalMinutes) / 60;
```

However, this is far from ideal. I know EF Core isn't ideal for complex queries, but I feel like I am missing something obvious here, is there something I can do to improve this?

Answer (score 6):

You might be able to leverage SQL Server's DATEDIFF function:

```cs
EF.Functions.DateDiffMinute(y.dateTo, DateTime.Now > y.dateFrom ? DateTime.Now : y.dateFrom)
```